# Next.js page crashes on browser back button click in Safari Mac/Iphone

Tags: reactjs, next.js, safari, akamai

With a few versions of IOS, The context object is undefined and when checked in the network tab the cached .json files in the browser disk cache throw "403" error on the click of back button.

Attached is the snapshot of the network tab. Works fine perfectly in the chrome browser.

This is the live site https://www.directv.com/forbusiness/ and it's accessible outside US there is no geofencing.

The context is undefined i.e ctx && ctx.req.cache, Snippet from one of the page

```
customerServiceIndex.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const page: string =
    ctx && ctx.query && ctx.query.page.length > 0
      ? ctx.query.page
      : `customer-support`;
  const path: string = `/dtvcms/dtvb/prod/customerservice.model.dtv.json`;
  let pages = ctx?.query?.page;
  let reqQueryParams: any;
  if (ctx.req) {
    reqQueryParams = ctx?.req?.query;
  } else {
    reqQueryParams = queryStringToObject(window.location.search);
  }
  let pagesInfoData = await fetchPageData(ctx, ctx.query.page, page, path);
  let cmsFeed = pagesInfoData?.cmsFeed;
  let feed = pagesInfoData?.feed;
  let fragments: any = feed && feed?.data ? feed.data : {};
  const contentProvider: ContentProvider = new ContentProvider();
  const data = contentProvider.buildDataFromLayout(
    // data1,
    fragments,
    page,
    pages,
    null,
    reqQueryParams,
    ctx.asPath
  );
  const initialProps = {
    data,
    err: cmsFeed == "" ? { statusCode: 404 } : undefined,
    feed: fragments?.pageProperties?.elements?.analyticsPageLoad?.analytics,
    cmsFeed: cmsFeed,
    page,
    pagePath: ctx.asPath,
    seo: fragments?.pageProperties?.elements || undefined,
    root: publicRuntimeConfig.root,
  };
  return initialProps;
};
```

---- Fetch Call ------

```
export const fetchPageData = async (
  ctx,
  page: string,
  currentPage,
  path: String
) => {
  console.log("currentPAge", currentPage);
  let authorization: string = ``;
  let cmsSource: string = ``;
  let contentSource: string = ``;
  page = ctx.query && ctx.query.page ? ctx.query.page : currentPage;
  let cmsVersion: string = ``;
  let pages: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } };
  let ctxuserAgent: string;
  let reqQueryParams: any;
  let is404page: boolean;
  let dbData: any;
  let feed: any = {};
  if (ctx?.req) {
    if (ctx?.query) {
      authorization = ctx?.query?.authorization || authorization;
      cmsSource = ctx?.query?.contentSourceBu6dot5;
      contentSource = ctx?.query?.contentSource || contentSource;
      pages = ctx?.query?.pages || {};
    }
    cmsVersion = ctx?.req?.query ? ctx?.req?.query.cmsversion : cmsVersion;
    ctxuserAgent =
      ctx?.req?.headers["idpctx-user-agent"] || ctx?.req?.headers["user-agent"];
    is404page = ctx?.query && ctx?.query?.is404Page === true;
    delete ctx.query.depVersion;
    delete ctx.query.authorization;
    delete ctx.query.pages;
    reqQueryParams = ctx?.req?.query;
  } else {
    dbData = (await dbGet(page)) as {
      [key: string]: { [key: string]: string };
    };
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
      cmsSource = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`;
    }
    reqQueryParams = queryStringToObject(window?.location?.search);
  }
  console.log(`DBDB`, dbData);
  console.log(`pages`, pages);
  const cmsFeed: string =
    pages &&
    pages[page] &&
    pages[page].cmsFeed &&
    pages[page].cmsFeed.length > 0
      ? pages[page].cmsFeed
      : dbData && dbData.cmsFeed && dbData.cmsFeed.length > 0
      ? dbData.cmsFeed
      : path;
  let cacheData: any =
    ctx && ctx?.req && ctx?.req?.cache ? ctx?.req?.cache : {};
  feed = await handleResponse(cacheData);
  if (cmsSource === "") {
    if (process?.env?.GN_6DOT5_CMS_HOST) {
      cmsSource = `${process?.env?.GN_6DOT5_CMS_HOST}`
      console.log("@@@@ ")
    } else {    
    cmsSource =
      publicRuntimeConfig && publicRuntimeConfig.prod === false
        ? `https://tst3.directv.com`
        : `https://www.directv.com`;
    }
  }
  const url = `${cmsSource}${cmsFeed}`;
  if (!Object.values(feed).some((v) => v)) {
    console.log("cms cache failed going to call api");
    feed = await failoverCmsCall(url, page);
  }
  return {
    feed,
    pages,
    cmsFeed,
  };
};
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has to do with the permissions on the

> https://www.directtv.com/dtvcms/etc

You don't have the necessary authorisation to view or fetch data from that page. If you own that domain, make sure you're responding with the right authorisation.

Comment: Just want to understand if the issue is with permission, Why is it browser specific and works well in chrome but crashes in safari.

Comment: I'm not sure. I used safari on desktop as well as chrome, and use on iphone too...I didn't experience your issues. I wasn't given access to the website at any time.

Comment: I'm not sure. I used safari on desktop as well as chrome, and use on iphone too...I didn't experience your issues. I wasn't given access to the website at any time.